# how do I send direct parameter into django def?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

How can I pass "g" as a direct value into def show-category?
What should I write in href in a tag?
How should I write related path?
I have follow code in html, models and views and related path.

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category'  %}" >Game</a></li>
```

......

```
class Listing_page (models.Model):
winner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='winner') 
urls= models.URLField(max_length=200000)
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='urls')
discription = models.CharField(max_length=280)
title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
open = models.BooleanField(default=True)
price = models.IntegerField()
item_category = [

    ('g','Game'),
    ('t','technology'),
    ('l','learn')
]
categori = models.CharField(choices=item_category,max_length=5000)
def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f"{self.id}:{self.title}"
```

........

```
def show_category(requst, categorys):
posts = Listing_page.objects.filter(categori=categorys, open=True)
return render(requst, 'auctions/category.html', {
    "posts": posts
})
```

......

```
path("category/<str:categorys>",views.show_category,name="category"),
```

Comment: `<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category'  categorys='your category' %}" >Game</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything in your code about "c". But I guess this is what you want to do:

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' 'g' %}" >Game</a></li>
```

Comment: exactly, I really appreciate your help, I corrected my question and get my answer